# How to instantiate many different classes from lists of names and classes in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, instantiation

I have a list of names like this:

```
names = ['name_1', 'name_2', ..., 'name_n']
```

and a list of classes (names of classes) like this:

```
classes = ['class_1', 'class_2', ..., 'class_n']
```

I can instantiate each class like this:

```
name_1 = class_1()
```

How can i instantiate all classes with given names at once (maybe using for loop )?

Comment: There are usually better ways to solve whatever problem it is you are trying to solve. Dynamic variable names are almost never the right solution. Is there a reason you have the class names as strings, rather than a list of the actual classes? Is there a reason you need to dynamically create variable names instead of storing the instances in a dict?

Comment: After reading your comments on the answers I suspect that this is probably an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You might want to ask a **new** question about the **real problem**, not about your **attempt** for solving it. :)

Comment: I'm trying to avoid that trap. I'm trying to instantiate all classes from a module at once.

Answer (score 6):

Why do you store the name of the classes instead of the classes themselves?

You could easily store the classes instead of the class names:

```
classes = [class1, class2]
```

And then use

```
[cls() for cls in classes]
```

To create the instances.

However dynamic variable names are rarely a good idea, why not store them in a dict?

```
d = {name: cls() for name, cls in zip(names, classes)}
```

And then access `d['name_1']` to get the instance for `'name_1'`.

The dictionary solution can also be used if you can't work around the list of class names problem. You simply create a dictionary, mapping the names to the actual classes:

```
name_to_class = {'class_1': class_1, 'class_2': class_2, ...}

d = {name: name_to_class[cls]() for name, cls in zip(names, classes)}
```

You could do it much simpler by using `globals` or such like, but that's a really bad habit and would expose everything (a security risk). Using your own dictionaries is generally considered the more "appropriate way".

Comment: I only have a list of names of classes. How should I store the classes instead?

Comment: I tried just as you described and got this: NameError: name 'name_1' is not defined

Comment: Where exactly did you get this? After using `d['name_1']`? Did you include the quotation marks around `name_1`?

Comment: after name_to_class = {'class_1': class_1, 'class_2': class_2, ...}

Comment: But that doesn't include a `name_1` how can it throw a NameError for `name_1`?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. NameError: name 'class_1' is not defined

Comment: @GGG Did you define `class_1` or not? The question said that `name_1 = class_1()` works, so `class_1` shouldn't throw a `NameError` otherwise that line wouldn't work too. Note that you have to put the `name_to_class` dictionary definition **after** the `class_1` definition.

Comment: I imported a module where all classes are defined. I'm also able to instantiate them one by one. Does it show that they're defined?

Comment: @GGG Yes, so the NameError doesn't make any sense, except you try to define the dictionary before importing or defining the classes.

Comment: I cannot create a dictionary name_to_class without importing a module with definitions of objects.

Comment: Sorry, you lost me there. You also couldn't use `class_1()` without importing `class_1` so I don't see the relevance (for this question)

Comment: @GGG No problem. Please don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer that helped you most. At least if any answer really solved your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Although not a recommended thing to do, just for demonstration purposes here you go

```
for index in range(len(names)):
    name = names[index]
    klass = classes[index]

    vars()[name] = vars()[klass]()
```

Comment: At least you didn't use `eval`... However it's still messy to work with `vars()`, `locals()` and `globals()`...

Comment: @MSeifert I have written a sort of disclaimer in the beginning. Haven't I?

Comment: You're right. I was just explaining what I consider "not recommended" about it.

Comment: @MSeifert No problem :)

Comment: Of course, you would have to have those classes `class_1`, `class_2` etc. defined in your scope.

Comment: I can instantiate them one by one, so I think they're defined.